# Get running totals for each month based on created_at date

Tags: mysql, sum, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get a running total for each month of this year.  So my ideal result would be something such as:

```
January   |  4 
February  |  5
March     |  8
April     | 10
May       | 12
June      | 14
July      | 16
August    | 17
September | 18
October   | 21
November  | 22
December  | 22
```

The basic count would just check against first of the month such as:

```
January 1 (sum where created_at < January 1, 2018)
February 1 (sum where created_at < February 1, 2018)
March 1 (sum where created_at < March 1, 2018)
April 1 (sum where created_at < April 1, 2018)
...
```

Doing it for one month at a time is easy, as I can just do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM businesses
WHERE created_at < CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), "-12-01 00:00:01")
```

I tried using one of the examples from another Stackoverflow answer, but it's not working quite as desired as it seems like the sort or something is messed up so the counts are not lining up right.

You can see schema build and current SQL here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c23cc/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME( created_at ) AS theMonth,
(
    SELECT
        count( * ) 
    FROM
        businesses AS u1 
    WHERE
        YEAR ( u1.created_at ) = YEAR ( businesses.created_at ) 
        AND u1.created_at <= date_ADD( last_day( businesses.created_at ), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
) AS totals 
FROM
    businesses 
WHERE
    YEAR ( businesses.created_at ) = YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) 
GROUP BY
    MONTHNAME( businesses.created_at ) 
ORDER BY
    MONTH ( businesses.created_at ) ASC
```

Comment: This kinda works but it ignores cumulative count from the years before. So January should be all previous years combined. And then February would be all previous years + January, and so on.  I think this might be better to just group by month and year and then loop through in PHP and figure it out.

Comment: Given that you hadn't referred to the previous year in your post, I assumed you were just interested in the current year.

Comment: try removing this: YEAR ( u1.created_at ) = YEAR ( businesses.created_at ) AND

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct since it does what I wanted it to do. I will test how it performs against simpler sql query and php loop. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me BUT I had an issue were the query took 4.5 seconds which when I had to run it several times it became an issue...I could not figure out how to speed it up. I went with a simpler query and php loop